# About Boole-Bonferroni inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

- Is there a version of the Boole-Bonferroni inequality with expectations of random variables?
- Is the only way the Boole-Bonferroni inequality can be satisfied is that no two of the events intersect? (And what is the analogous statement in an expectation version of the Boole-Bonferroni inequality)

Answer (score 0):

(i) You can turn the probability of an event into the expectation of an indicator function

(ii) For equality you want the probabilities of the intersections to be $0$

Comment: (1) Is it possible to use an indicator function which takes some non-trivial value on an event (some number which depends on the event) and 0 outside it? I want to convert the Boole-Bonferroni into a statement about a bunch of functions which are say compactly supported on the events and all their possible intersections. Like thinking of the events as being sets in a measure space. (2) Yes, thats the intuition but how does one prove that this all intersections being null is an "iff" condition?

Comment: @user6818: What would $\displaystyle {\mathbb P}\biggl(\bigcup_{i} A_i\biggr)$ turn into in that case?